# How do I enable multitouch support on synaptics?

Tags: multi-touch

I'm using Vaio which uses Synaptics touch pad. Multi touch gestures worked with no trouble on my previous installed operating system, windows 7. Now it seems like I can't use multi touch gestures on Ubuntu 12.10 at all. How exactly do I install the right drivers to make multi touch possible on my laptop. Thank you in advanced.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Install the DKMS driver package provided in https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/308191 (comment #115, #116). Reboot, and go to `System > Preferences > Mouse > Touchpad` and select "Two-finger scrolling".

[credit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad)

Comment: I already did that a few days back following the instructions from Ubuntu. but unfortunately after installing the package, all it did was make all software installations appear as an "error" when it isn't. That package doesn't even exist in my software centre now.

Comment: Could you give us the information about how you have installed

Comment: I went to https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/308191 (comment #115,#116). I rebooted, and tried going to two finger scroll settings. I could not click two finger scroll. Synaptics says it detects only one finger on my touchpad